# APA 6th Edition - Quoting

Tags: quotations

The whole quote is:
"We children didn’t quite fathom the significance of what happened on 27 May 1967. I do remember the shrieks of joy after the result was announced, laughter and a mass of tears. Mum told me we would be counted in the census now, along with the sheep and cattle. She also said we would be free people at last. I never quite knew what she meant, only that this was a big deal."

But I only really want to take three parts out of the quote like this;

“we children didn’t quite fathom the significance of what happened on 27 May 1967...Mum told me that we would be counted in the census now...She also said we would be free people at last”

How do I do that correctly?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it seeks guidance as to how to interpret an arbitrary set of guidelines; it does not allow for other accepted conventions.

Answer (score 1):

You're about right.

According to Paige Jackson, writing on the [APA blog](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aaoSfy6yjrlMJ%3ablog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2011/04/ellipseswhen-and-how.html%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us),

> Sometimes, the missing text occurs within two or more sentences.  In that case, four dots are used—a period and three ellipses—to signal that the gap in text includes the end of one sentence and the beginning of another:

Also, APA requires a space between each period of an ellipsis. Note that when used together with the above rule, the first period does not have a space but the subsequent periods that make up the ellipsis do.

So your final quote would be (keep in mind that ellipses don't render properly here, though most word processors handle it automatically):

> “We children didn’t quite fathom the significance of what happened on 27 May 1967. . . . Mum told me that we would be counted in the census now . . . She also said we would be free people at last.”

I personally wouldn't omit the "along with the sheep and cattle" portion.

Non-digital source: *Publication Manual of the American Psychological Association, 6th ed* pp 170-173

Comment: In apa referencing you aren't allowed to use a quote over 40 words? is that correct?

Comment: @brooke You can, it just has to be in a standalone block of text. But no, you shouldn't have a long quote in the middle of a paragraph. If you do put it in a block of text, you really should include the entire passage without the ellipses.

Comment: Okay!
Could i also have it like this or is that badly structured? 

“We children didn’t quite fathom the significance of what happened on 27 May 1967“ (Huggins, 2007, pg 2). Jackie then goes on to say “Mum told me we would be counted in the census now, along with the sheep and cattle. She also said we would be free people at last“ (Huggins, 2007, pg 2).

Comment: @brooke I wouldn't do that. Unless you plan on treating each of those excerpts individually with your own commentary, I think it would be better to group the passages in one quote and follow it with your analysis. I think your original construction (with the proper ellipses) is much better.

Comment: Alright, thankyou very much for your help!